# How can I interpret expression $l(x-t)$, where $l$ is a distribution in a single variable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

In the appendix B of "Functional Analysis" by Peter Lax, author claims that for any pair of distributions $l$ and $m$ in a single variable,
$$
u = l(x+t) + m(x-t)
$$
is a solution of 1D wave equation
$$
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0
$$
in the sense of distributions.

However I cannot understand the expressions $l(x+t)$ and $m(x-t)$. In the same book the composition of  a distribution and an invertible $C^{\infty}$ mapping has been defined, but $(x,t)\mapsto x+t$ is not invertible.

How can I interpret $l(x+t)$? And with that proper interpretaion, how can I show that such distribution is a solution of a wave equation in a distribution sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A broad answer is to consider distributions as limit of sequences of smooth functions converging in the sense of distributions, from which many operators can be applied naturally and in a consistent way (derivative, Fourier transform, change of variable, composition with functions, convolution, tensor product, multiplication with a smooth function..)
$$\langle l(x),\phi(x)\rangle =\lim_{n\to \infty}  \int_\Bbb{R} l_n(x) \phi(x)dx$$
where $l_n(x)=\langle l(y),n\varphi(n(x-y))\rangle$ given some $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}),\int\varphi=1$ fixed a priori.

$$\langle l(x+t),\Phi(x,t)\rangle= \lim_{n\to \infty}  \int_{\Bbb{R}^2} l_n(x+t) \Phi(x,t)dxdt$$